# Вставить текст в закладки MS Word

Tags: java

Доброго времени суток! Есть шаблон Word(`.doc`), его необходимо открыть и на место закладок, которые имеются в документе, вставить текст, после сохранить как новый файл. Текст, который вносится в документ, должен быть прописан в коде.
Код который я смог реализовать прилагаю ниже, прошу помощи)

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.usermodel.Range;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem;

public class Zamena_text_file {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Путь к шаблону
        String filename = "C:\\S.doc";
        POIFSFileSystem fs = null;

        try 
        {
            fs = new POIFSFileSystem(new FileInputStream(filename));
            HWPFDocument doc = new HWPFDocument(fs);

            // добавление данных вместо "меток" в документе
            Range range = doc.getRange();
            range.replaceText("<name>", "953");
            //range.tab("asa");

            // создание нового файла
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Отчет.doc");
            // записать данные в файл
            doc.write(out);
            // заставляем поток закончить передачу данных.
            out.flush();
            // закрыть поток данных. 
            out.close();
            // вывод сообщения в консоле
            System.out.println("Файл Отчет.doc успешно создан!");
            // Команда для запуска Excel файла
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c C:\\Отчет.doc");                         
        }       
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            // В случае ошибки(ок) вывести в консоль систем.ошибки 
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }      
    }    
}
```

Comment: не могли бы поподробнее описать что у Вас не получается и с какими сложностями Вы сталкиваетесь, чтобы было понятно какую именно Вам помощь нужно оказать и где.

Comment: У меня есть шаблон документа .doc, в нем есть определенная форма с информацией, есть закладки созданные штатным функционалом word(закладка например number_project), эта закладка никак не видна на листе документа(просто выделил фрагмент строки и добавил туда закладку), так и вот нужно дописать код, чтобы именно по имени этой закладки именно туда и вставлялся текст из скрипта. Надеюсь более понятнее объяснил

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример кода для замены всех закладок:

```
Bookmarks bookmarks = document.getBookmarks();
for (int i = 0; i < bookmarks.getBookmarksCount(); i++){
    Bookmark bookmark = bookmarks.getBookmark(i);
    String value = getValue(bookmark.getName());
    setTextInBookmark(bookmark, document, value);
}

private static void setTextInBookmark(Bookmark bookmark, HWPFDocument document, String text) {
    final Range range = new Range(bookmark.getStart(), bookmark.getEnd(), document);
    if (range.text().length() > 0) {
        range.replaceText(text, false); // если в закладке уже есть значение - заменяем
    }
    else {
        range.insertBefore(text);
    }
}
//получение значения закладки в зависимости от ее наименования
private static String getValue(String bookmarkName) {
    if (bookmarkName.equals("name1")) {
        return "1";
    }
    if (bookmarkName.equals("name2")) {
        return "2";
    }
    //....
    return "default value";
}
```

Comment: Допустим у меня 5 закладок, у каждой свое название и у каждой закладки должно быть свое значение после замены, как это реализовать? Подскажите если не сложно, просто я только начинаю изучать java.. Пока что сложновато в обучении(

Comment: добавил в ответ

Comment: Спасибо огромное!) Вы прям бооог!! Надеюсь разберусь в коде самостоятельно, иначе опять возможно вас придется побеспокоить:)

Comment: Все вроде сделал по уму, но компилятор ругается на строку с for
###################################################
for (Bookmark bookmark: document.getBookmarks())
{
String value = getValue(bookmark.getName());
setTextInBookmark(bookmark, document, value);
}
###########################################
Вот что пишет в ошибках
###########################################
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable
at Zamena_text_file.main(Zamena_text_file.java:28)

Comment: внес правки в ответ

Comment: Ууурраааа!!! Все заработало) Спасибо огромное еще раз)

Comment: Пожалуйста. В таком случае, отметьте ответ как верный